# depicting blowups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, blowup

Is there a way to make nice images of blowups?

For instance you can always find a picture of the blowup of $y^2 = x^2 +x^3$

for example, [https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arapura/graph/nodal.html](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Earapura/graph/nodal.html)

But I what if I want to blowup $x^2 - y^5=0$, something that requires multiple blowups?

How do I make a nice drawing of it?

I'm looking for something that works nice in my browser, some matlab code, or an easy to use javascript library.

Comment: When you refer to *multiple blow-ups*, are you referring to an *animated graphic* such as a \*.png file, as opposed to a static graphic.  I've never worked with animated graphics before, but I infer from your query that it somehow involves consolidating multiple graphics files.  Somewhat off-topic to this forum, I know that the [Latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) plug-in called [Asymptote](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/) can operate *stand-alone*, **outside of Latex**, sending the output to (for example) jpegs.  ...see next comment.

Comment: If you go that route, I strongly recommend the Charles Staat tutorial.  A couple of things are unclear to me.  I don't know if you can *feed* the Asymptote (stand-alone) code a *parameter*, which would certainly be what you want.  If so, then I know that (for example) Java can easily programmatically invoke a module, varying the parameter sent to the module, so that you programmatically generate the (static) graphics files (i.e. jpeg files).  Also unknown to me is if it is feasible to use the group of static graphics files to construct the (animated) \*.png file.

Comment: Animated would be really cool, but I am just looking for pictures. Maybe there was some library for geomiters that use blowups a lot where you could call some function Blowup(x_1,x_2,x_3,...) and it will spit out the picture for you

Comment: If you are just looking (for example) for a *single* static picture, then it is unclear what you mean by *blow-up*.  I know, for example, that the Asymptote stand-alone that I referred to allows you to totally control the size of the generated graphic.  I would be extremely surprised if this type of facility was not also available in a wide variety of software packages, most of whom would not be associated with Latex.  For the other two generally used Latex-plugins that I know of, PSTricks and PGF-Tikz, I don't know whether either will operate stand-alone, or whether either will output jpegs.

Comment: Since I regularly use Asymptote, I just googled on "Asymptote Latex parameter" and found [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582244/asymptote-sending-a-parameter-to-function-in-contour/582275).

Comment: @user2661923 As in the tags, a [blow-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up) is an operation that algebraic geometers do on their varieties. OP means they want to have a (possibly static) graph of how a variety looks after blowing it up at some point.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Very interesting, and totally new to me.  Does *blow-up* necessarily involve *3-dimensional* graphics?  Beyond that, is there something intrinsic about a *blow-up* that would prevent its *graph* (either 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional)  from being represented by a (hand-crafted) mathematical function?

Comment: @jackozee FYR, the tags algebraic geometry and algebraic curves are added by me and not the OP. From the link in the post I suppose the tags are the correct ones....

Comment: My OP was tagged AG, blowups, and plotting. @user2661923 I would like to see a picture of the curve blown up at point. I'm not sure if you mean scaled or not. A blow up of  a point in a plane (which is all I'm looking for atm, nothing more complicated) essentially stretches the singularity point so that the resulting curve is smooth, and it keeps the same tangent space (blowups of a point in a plane replaces the point with the projectivized tangent space at the point). Now I want to create some pircures that illustrate this. I can draw some out by had, but the link has a really nice image

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by *scaled*.  What my previous comment referred to is: if you were in a class where the teacher handed you a jpeg image of a *blow-up*, such as what you are desiring, and assigned you the problem of creating a mathematical function to represent each point in the graph (or jpeg image), could you **routinely** do it?  If so, then I think that it is *game-over.*  If not, then I am way out of my depth, and regrettably, I've led you down the wrong investigative path.  You **might** then look for some canned software that represents the blow-up image as a math function.

Comment: If you want to to do a blow up of $y^2 = x^3 + x^2$ for example, this has a singularity at $(0,0)$. We can blow up, ie stretch the point so we get curve without a singularity.. We can seperate the lines at the origin by introducing $t=\frac{y}{x}$ which represent the slopes of the lines at the singularity. We can reparametrize this line by $y=xt \implies y^2 -x^2(x+1) =0 \implies x^2(t^2 -x-1)=0$. Now we have the exceptional curve $x=0$ of multiplicity 2 and our new "blown up curve $t^2 = x +1$ Now we can graph $x=0$ and $t^2 = x+1$, but this does not give the illustration of whats happening

Comment: Is this what you mean by finding a function for each point? because you can find the curves given by the blowup pretty easily, but seeing the tangent curves seperated by the blowup is what I'm looking for visually

Comment: Tim Dokchitser has Magma code that uses LaTeX to produce pictures of regular models of curves which are obtained by repeatedly blowing up. I'm not sure it's exactly what you're looking for, but it at least allows you to see how the various components intersect. https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/newton/